# Unhashable type : 'list' Error

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dictionary

I'm getting this error for the following code

```
def cleaning(CURRENT,STRING,NEXT):
    data.ix[data[NEXT].str.contains(STRING,na=False),CURRENT] =...
    data[NEXT][data[NEXT].str.contains(STRING,na=False)]
d = ['lower','Less']
c = a[5:]
for x,y in zip(range(len(c)),d):
    cleaning(c[x],d,c[x+1])
    cleaning(c[x],d,c[x+2])
```

Here, data is a pandas DataFrame.
However for the same function I'm getting no error in the following code

```
a = ['UBC','LBC', 'HC', 'FC', 'P:C/F','P', 'A', 'Sex']
b = ['upper','lower','hair','footwear']
for x,y in zip(range(len(a)),b):
    cleaning(a[x],y,a[x+1])
    cleaning(a[x],y,a[x+2])
```

I know this is because we can't use a list as the key in a dict but I'm not sure how that's happening here and why is it working for one loop and not the other.

Comment: You are passing in `d`, a list, as the `STRING` argument. Did you mean to pass in `y` instead?

Comment: Also, what is `a`? If `a` is a list of lists, then `c[...]` is a list and that's then passed in as `NEXT`.

Comment: Please do include the **full traceback** of your exception. I had a hunch and I just confirmed it, but a traceback would make this far clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `d`, a list, as the `STRING` argument:

```
d = ['lower','Less']
# ...
    cleaning(c[x],d,c[x+1])
    #             ^
```

Your second example works, you pass in `y` instead, which is a single element from the `b` list:

```
b = ['upper','lower','hair','footwear']
for x,y in zip(range(len(a)),b):
    # ^ one element from b   ^
    cleaning(a[x],y,a[x+1])
    #             ^
```

The `pandas.Series.str.contains` method accepts regexes by default, and `re.compile` uses a dictionary as a cache to hold compiled patterns. Because you passed in a list, you get your error:

```
>>> pandas.Series(['aa', 'bb', 'cc']).str.contains(['a'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1458, in contains
    regex=regex)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 222, in str_contains
    regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 237, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[cachekey]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The fix is to pass in `y` instead of `d`:

```
for x, y in zip(range(len(c)) ,d):
    cleaning(c[x], y, c[x + 1])
    cleaning(c[x], y, c[x + 2])
```

You may want to come up with better variable names; one-letter names are hard to distinguish and easily lead to errors like these.

Comment: Aah what a dumb thing to do! Thanks I'll keep that in mind.